# Creating a Waffle

Tags: javascript

I’m working on a fun task to make robust validation for a password. It’s part of a username and login system. Below is only my code for validation, it is inside a function

```
valid = False
while not valid:
         valid = True
         Password = input(“Please input password”)
         if len(password) < 5:
                valid = False
                break
```

So basically I’m trying to make it that the password has to be longer than 5 characters. There is actually no syntax error. However the code just accepts any input with taking into account that I’ve put ——-len(password)<5: ——-
My problem is that it doesn’t check size of string

Sorry in advance if I’m missing something blatantly obvious

Comment: You've got `Password` with a capital P as your target for the input statement, and `password` with a lowercase p in your `len(password)` part.

Comment: @DavyM just a typing error in reality they’re both the same

Answer (score 1):

use `continue` not `break`

`break` means to break the while loop and fall out the bottom

`continue` means skip the rest of the code and go back to the top of the while loop and recheck the condition

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `valid = True`. Because it now will automaticly repeate the code without running the password code. And replace the break with continue.